# Is there a mistake in the token validation documentation? Or am I getting this wrong?

Tags: google-signin

In this section of the sign-in guide,
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library,

There is this code snippet

```
# Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(),CLIENT_ID)
```

This correctly validates the token when I pass my *server*'s client ID, but fails when I pass the android app's client it.

However, the comment suggests that it should be the android app's client ID that should get passed here! And that also makes more sense from a security perspective.

---

Further down, I can find the following `Python` code sample

```
    # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
    # idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
    # if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
    #     raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')
```

I have played around a bit and it seems to me that  `idinfo["aud"]` key carries the client ID of the *server*, where as `idinfo["azp"]` carries the client ID of the client.

If I understand it right, in this line we are supposed to verify the client id of the *android app client*!
So it should read:

```
    if idinfo['azp'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
        raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')
```

---

I feel like I must be getting something wrong here, but what is it?